# Alternative proof to $(b'd)^2\leq (b'b)(d'd)$

Tags: statistics, inequality, self-learning

> Let $b$ and $d$ be any two $p\times 1$ vectors. Show that
>   $$(b'd)^2\leq (b'b)(d'd)$$ with equality if and only if $b=cd$.

I get this proof from the book.

Let $b-xd$ where $x$ is an scalar. Since the length of $b-xd>0$ for $b-xd\neq 0$

$$0<(b-xd)'(b-xd)=b'b-xd'b-b'xd+x^2d'd$$
$$=b'b-2x(b'd)+x^2(d'd)$$

since the expression is a quadratic form in $x$
$$0<b'b-\frac{(b'd)^2}{d'd}+\frac{(b'd)^2}{d'd}-2x(b'd)+x^2(d'd)$$
$$=b'b-\frac{(b'd)^2}{d'd}+(d'd)\Big(x-\frac{b'd}{d'd}\Big)^2$$

choosing $x=\frac{b'd}{d'd}$

$$0<b'b-\frac{(b'd)^2}{d'd}$$

Then $(b'd)^2<(b'b)(d'd)$ if $b\neq xd$ for some $x$.
Note that if $b=cd$ then $0=(b-cd)'(b-cd)$ and the same argument produces $(b'd)^2=(b'b)(d'd)$

Is there any proof more intuitive? I didn't get the idea of using $b-xd$ to proof. In the last steps I see that work, but I don't understood what is the idea behind.

Comment: The name for this result is "Cauchy-Schwarz inequality". Your proof can be shortened by using the discriminant of the quadratic inequality.

Comment: @JeanMarie I know that is Cauchy-Schwarz, I just don't understood how they get this proof.

Comment: All right. As you did not mentionned the name and that you have used the tag "self learning", I thought you were not aware of the name. I don't know a proof that does not use a reasoning on a quadratic. But, as I said, usually one directly uses the discriminant.

Comment: the length of $b-xd$ is non-negative, for any choice of $x$, so it should be for this particular choice as well. I am not sure if there's a simpler proof, though one can think of more complicated ones.

Comment: Intuition: $b'b$ and $d'd$ are squares of lengthes of vectors of dimension $p$ while $b'd$ is their scalar product, known to be equal to the product of their lengthes times a cosine, hence the LHS is the RHS times the square of a cosine, which is at most $1$, qed.

Comment: @Did You mean $$(b'd)^2=||b||^2||d||^2\cos^2(\theta)=(b'b)(d'd)\cos^2(\theta)\leq (b'b)(d'd)$$ since $cos^2(\theta)\leq 1$